# Cypress doesn't stub my requests when using fixtures

Tags: javascript, cypress

I am trying to create e2e tests using Cypress for my Angular application. So far I managed to get the basics sorted, now I am trying to stub network requests.

I have created some fixtures and created a custom command:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('login', (email, password, happy = false) => {
    let auth_url = Cypress.env('auth_url');
    console.log(auth_url);

    cy.get('[data-cy=email]').as('email');
    cy.get('[data-cy=password]').as('password');
    cy.get('[data-cy=login-form]').as('form');

    cy.location('pathname').should('equal', '/login');

    cy.get('@email').type(email);
    cy.get('@password').type(password);

    cy.get('@form').submit();

    cy.fixture(happy ? 'successful-login.json' : 'failed-login.json').then((json) => {
        console.log(json);
        cy.intercept(`${auth_url}/connect/token`, json).then(() => {
            if (!happy) return;

            cy.fixture('current-user.json').then((currentUser) => {
                console.log(currentUser);
                cy.intercept(`/users/**`, currentUser);
            });
        });;
    });
});
```

My fixtures are:
**successful-login.json**:

```
{
    "access_token": "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjRGNEVBQzE4N0Y5QUM1MTE4NjhFNTQ5OTA5RUIzOEQxIiwidHlwIjoiYXQrand0In0.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.e-TX3u3o8UJZ9nq7nyuMFWfRyjEh55CwWQSHhfFxt677_qCu6pJ1cuHHOMjMV0lc-hTXjbe-4lZ7oOVfOZA_gByFo6mFpq8co__Npj1YpMt18LOSuewspKldffgCZQm2wIKTqSmMIQoFDRoUmAmcBsbJZIqSx4KMYBz7OfsBmdU7TeNi8bjtLcglzBxgYko7njJuC9j1EarR9BC-tjPIb0eoROclfQlPcYb05T4RRMzi3dpFExEXzFMaiMnR8_q0VOPWzeL0phFcjm-r1nVTVvrRcCtvI3GPPxr5EshT4XHcg6pmxx8BUlWXI6u1gSnWShmvXP5n87HJTCjsJh8sEQ",
    "expires_in": 3600,
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "scope": "identity:read identity:write sxp:read sxp:write"
}
```

**failed-login.json**

```
{ "error": "invalid_grant", "error_description": "invalid_username_or_password" }
```

And finally, **current-user.json**:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "failure": false,
    "error": null,
    "result": {
        "jobTitle": null,
        "image": null,
        "createdBy": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
        "updatedBy": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
        "dateCreated": "2021-02-26T11:23:18.074899",
        "dateUpdated": "2021-02-26T11:23:18.0749379",
        "deleted": false,
        "roles": null,
        "id": "a233d408-25c2-486a-ae38-933199b569dd",
        "emailConfirmed": true,
        "concurrencyStamp": "0246797d-fd93-4723-a142-95d5213f9ec7",
        "phoneNumber": null,
        "phoneNumberConfirmed": false,
        "twoFactorEnabled": false,
        "lockoutEnd": "2021-03-17T16:04:59.7781333+00:00",
        "lockoutEnabled": true,
        "accessFailedCount": 0
    },
    "message": null
}
```

The spec file looks like this:

```
/// <reference types="Cypress" />

describe('login workflow', () => {
    it('does not work with wront credentials', () => {
        const email = 'user@example.com';
        const password = 'test';

        cy.visit('/');

        cy.login(email, password).as('loginRequest').then(() => {
            cy.contains('.mat-simple-snackbar span', 'Invalid username or password.');
        });
    });

    it('happy path test', () => {
        const email = 'user@example.com';
        const password = 'test';

        cy.visit('/');
        cy.location('pathname').should('equal', '/login');

        cy.login(email, password, true).as('loginRequest').then(() => {
            cy.location('pathname').should('equal', '/');
        });
    });
});
```

The issue I have is that even though the tests both say the routes are being stubbed:

[image]

The actual request, isn't:

[image]

The first test passes because the username and password are incorrect, even without stubbing the response, but the second test fails:

[image]

Because it doesn't stub the response:

[image]

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having a new intercept set up inside the `.then()` of a previous intercept seems like it might be a problem. There's nothing executing after that last intercept that would trigger it.

Since intercepts should be set up **before the trigger occurs**, the following should be (nearly) logically equivalent,

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('login', (email, password, happy = false) => {

  cy.intercept(`/users/**`, { fixture: 'current-user.json' });

  const auth_url = Cypress.env('auth_url');
  const loginFixture = happy ? 'successful-login.json' : 'failed-login.json';
  cy.intercept(`${auth_url}/connect/token`, { fixture: loginFixture });

  cy.get('[data-cy=email]').as('email');
  cy.get('[data-cy=password]').as('password');
  cy.get('[data-cy=login-form]').as('form');

  cy.location('pathname').should('equal', '/login');

  cy.get('@email').type(email);
  cy.get('@password').type(password);

  cy.get('@form').submit();
});
```

The only difference is the `/users` intercept is set up even if the `auth` intercept fails, but you are controlling that outcome anyway (with `happy`), so this should produce the same result